# How to find the difference of dates in consecutive rows and update the table column respectively in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table with below-mentioned columns:

- ID (int) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
- DOCTOR_ID (int)
- PATIENT_IN_TIME (datetime)
- AVG_CHECKUP_TIME

I want to subtract row 1 PATIENT_IN_TIME with row 2 PATIENT_IN_TIME and save the result in minutes to AVG_CHECKUP_TIME.

Suppose there are 5 entries in the table.

```
|1|2|2018-03-22 02:49:51|NULL|

|2|2|2018-03-22 02:56:37|NULL|
```

So I want to find the difference of both the rows and save the minutes in the last column. So, the output would look like,

```
|1|2|2018-03-22 02:49:51|7|

|2|2|2018-03-22 02:56:37|NULL|
```

Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Does your table have only two rows?  If not, it is not clear what you are asking for.

Comment: the `lead` equivalent for mysql

Comment: So per doctor id, you want to get the difference between the next checkin and current checkin time?

Comment: i supposed a self join over `row_number` should do this to mimic the  `lead` functionality

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> create table tbl 
> (
>   id int auto_increment primary key, 
>   doctor_id int, 
>   patient_in_time datetime, 
>   avg_checkup_time datetime
> );
>
> insert into tbl values
> (1, 2, '2018-03-22 02:49:51', null),
> (2, 2, '2018-03-22 02:56:37', null),
> (3, 2, '2018-03-22 03:00:15', null),
> (4, 2, '2018-03-22 03:03:37', null);
> ```

> ```
> select t1.id, t1.doctor_id, t1.patient_in_time, 
>        timestampdiff(minute, t1.patient_in_time, 
>                       (select patient_in_time 
>                        from tbl where id = t1.id +1)) diff
> from tbl t1
> ```
>
> ```
> id | doctor_id | patient_in_time     | diff
> -: | --------: | :------------------ | ---:
>  1 |         2 | 2018-03-22 02:49:51 |    6
>  2 |         2 | 2018-03-22 02:56:37 |    3
>  3 |         2 | 2018-03-22 03:00:15 |    3
>  4 |         2 | 2018-03-22 03:03:37 | null
> ```

<kbd>*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=a1690808633e0523a46786bc6ede5639)*</kbd>

As per comments if order is set by `patient_in_time` then you can use an scalar subquery that returns next row in this way:

> ```
> select t1.id,
>        t1.doctor_id,
>        t1.patient_in_time,
>        timestampdiff(minute, 
>                      t1.patient_in_time, 
>                      (select   patient_in_time
>                       from     tbl 
>                       where    patient_in_time > t1.patient_in_time
>                       order by patient_in_time asc
>                       limit 1)) diff
> from   tbl t1
> order by patient_in_time
> ```
>
> ```
> id | doctor_id | patient_in_time     | diff
> -: | --------: | :------------------ | ---:
>  1 |         2 | 2018-03-22 02:49:51 |    6
>  2 |         2 | 2018-03-22 02:56:37 |    3
>  3 |         2 | 2018-03-22 03:00:15 |    3
>  4 |         2 | 2018-03-22 03:03:37 | null
> ```

<kbd>*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=0b0001e56c68d00e37628e6eef2d98e1)*</kbd>

Comment: What if the ids are not in order?

Comment: What column set the order?

Comment: patient_in_time